# How to change number of columns in a row for different display sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have list of products:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Item3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">Item4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Item5</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Item6</div>
</div>
```

How can I change it so for smaller displays (sm,xs) I'll have 2 items per row, and for larger (lg) 4 item per row ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply add more classes according to the viewport width:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item5</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item6</div>
</div>
```

The above gives you an output of 4 columns for larger viewports, 3 for medium and 2 for smaller.

Since a row can be comprised of 12 columns, assigning the value `6` appended to the class that corresponds to the breakpoint you want will give each column 50% of the row width.

To quote BootStrap directly:

> Extra small devices Phones (<768px)   Small devices Tablets
>   (≥768px)  Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)    Large devices Desktops
>   (≥1200px)

- **Extra small devices Phones** = `col-xs-n`
- **Small devices Tablets** = `col-sm-n`
- **Medium devices Desktops** = `col-md-n`
- **Large devices Desktops** = `col-lg-n`

EDIT - as per OP's comment if you want 2 columns side by side at smaller viewports, you'll need to add them all in the same row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item6</div>
</div>
```

This will give you the following output at smaller viewports

```
Item 1 | Item 2
Item 3 | Item 4
Item 5 | Item 6
```

Comment: In this case for sm I'll get rows: `'Item1|Item2'`, `'Item3| '`, `'Item4|Item5'`, `'Item6| '`. Instead of `Item1|Item2`, `Item3|Item4`, `Item5|Item6`.

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa Yes, that's expected behaivour... Item 3 and Item 4 are in different rows... You'll need to add all div's into the same row if you want that.

Comment: Can this be rearranged so that it is `ITEM1|ITEM3` on row1, then `ITEM 2|ITEM 4` on row2 and `ITEM 5|ITEM 6` on row3 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Grid options:

```
Extra small  <544px  .col-xs-
Small        ≥544px  .col-sm-
Medium       ≥768px  .col-md-
Large        ≥992px  .col-lg-
Extra large  ≥1200px .col-xl-
```

Source:[Grid Options](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Add multiple classes to specify different rules for different devices.

Snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item4</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item5</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Different column sizes by keeping in mind of different devices in your mind.

```
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

For better understanding head over to this link : [Bootstrap responsive for Different Devices](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed)

and try resizing the window to see how the grid size changes when the width and height of the window changes.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap  work as this type of grid Ex.
Demo link [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options) [Demo](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

```
Extra small
<544px => .col-xs-
Small
≥544px => .col-sm-
Medium
≥768px => .col-md-
Large
≥992px => .col-lg-
 Extra large
≥1200px
.col-xl-
```

```html
<link href="https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9">Item3</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9">Item4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9">Item5</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9">Item6</div>
</div>
</div>
```